# How can I start a systemd service after one of its dependencies starts?

Tags: systemd

I'm on a Debian jessie system. I have configured the `cron` service to depend on the `slapd` and the `nscd` services. I have done this by creating a systemd "drop-in" config file here:

```
/etc/systemd/system/cron.service.d/foo.conf
```

which has this content:

```
[Unit]
Requires=slapd.service nscd.service
After=slapd.service nscd.service
```

With this in place, I can restart the `slapd` service, and the `cron` service will restart also, so that's fine. However, if I first stop `slapd` and then start it again in a separate command, the `cron` service will not come up again. This has bitten me when I updated some system packages that apparently caused `slapd` to stop then start in two distinct steps - I failed to notice the problem, so cron didn't run for many days.

Anyway, back to the question: Is it possible to configure a service so that it starts automatically when I start its dependency? Like what happens during system startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need cron to restart if slapd restarts? I wouldn't think so. Changing the `Requires=` to a `Wants=` should solve your problem: stopping slapd will have no effect on cron.

Comment: True, if `slapd` starts again after being stopped I'm fine with `cron` remaining in active (running) state. Because your solution addresses my main issue I'm accepting your answer. It's a somewhat dangerous solution though - if `slapd` does _not_ come up again the `cron` service _will_ have a problem.

Comment: Another option is to add something like `ExecStartPost="systemctl start cron"` to slapd's unit file.